# How to check value of column is false i want to insert my data

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

I am creating C# application if the last value of trigger_0 is False insert my current date and time, help me to solve this:

```
        String test = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        String test1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdt = con.CreateCommand();
        cmdt.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdt.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 trigger_0 FROM WINDATAA  ORDER BY trigger_0 DESC ";
        cmdt.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY trigger_0` is inconclusive (possibly non deterministic) because a lot of `trigger_0` values are `False`. So you never know which record is returned.

Comment: What type is your Id, Guid or int?

Comment: or maybe another type?

Comment: trigger_0 is the default value is false if value is false i want to insert my current date and time

Comment: ok but what kind of ID do you use? what type

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to update all rows:

```
UPDATE WINDATAA
SET [date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETUTCDATE(), 121)
   ,[time] = LEFT(CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS TIME), 5)
WHERE [triggger_0] = 'false' -- or [triggger_0] = 0 if boolean
```

If you need to modify only the last, you can use some id if you have, or get the maximum/last date in advanced and use the value in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just get result from your executed query and see whether it is `true`. If `true` then just insert your data:

```
bool trigger = true;
SqlCommand cmdt = con.CreateCommand();
cmdt.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
var result = cmdt.ExecuteScalar();       
bool.TryParse(result, out trigger);
if (trigger == false) {
    // insert your data. For example:
   string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.FooTable (id,username) VALUES (@id,@username)"; 
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db.Connection);
   string preventNull = null;
   preventNull = preventNull == null ? "Is not null" : "Hey!";
   string fooUserName = null;
   fooUserName = fooUserName == null ? "Bob not null" : "Hey!";
   command.Parameters.Add("@id", preventNull );
   command.Parameters.Add("@username", fooUserName );      
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: yes correct trigger_0 is false then i insert my current data and time

Comment: @Annisha Please, see my updated answer. I've added `NULL` checking and prevent inserting `NULL` values.

Comment: @Annisha Feel free to ask any question. If you don't have any question, then feel free to mark my reply as answer to simplify future search of other people.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it properly you want to check if the last created item in your table has a value true or false. If the field *time* in your database describes the creation time you can just order the items by date and time e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 trigger_0 FROM WINDATAA  ORDER BY date, time DESC
```

Another option I see is if the id of your table is an integer then you can just order the items by Id:

```
SELECT TOP 1 trigger_0 FROM WINDATAA  ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Then you can create a statement in C#, and use the data of the object if it's needed